# Can you help me derive PACF for moving average process MA(1)?

Tags: time-series, moving-average, acf-pacf

I am really lost with the task. Can someone provide literature or possibly the derivation for the following:

Assuming that the best linear predictor of $X_{h+1}$ can be estimated as $\hat{X}_{h+1} = \sum^h_{i=1} \phi_{hi} X_{h+1-i}$, compute the PACF $\alpha(2)$ of the moving average process MA(1) defined by $X_t = Q_t + \theta Q_{t-1}$, where $\{Q_t\}$ is a White Noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: See e.g. Wei (2006), http://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/CVEN6833/lectures/wwts-book.pdf, section 3.2.1

Comment: Thank you for the reference. But there is nothing about linear predictors :(

Comment: If this is self study, then edit your question by adding the self-study tag.  Also, what do you mean by $\alpha(2)$?  Do you mean the partial autocorrelation at lag 2?  Section 3.2.1 in Wei refers back to eq. 2.3.19 in section 2.3 which is all about linear predictors.